# Get test case outcome/result using TFS API

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

how to Get **Current** test case result especially that which Active,
because alawys i get Passed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDKAI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could first retrieve Active test cases is to use the ITestPlan.QueryTestPoints method, and TestPointState.Ready property.

The following code snippet will **list all the Active test cases' Id**. Please take a look at below:

```
ITestManagementService testManagementService = testHelper.GetTestManagementService();
            //Get Team Project
            ITestManagementTeamProject teamProjects= testManagementService.GetTeamProject("TeamProjectName");
 //Get the test plan
            ITestPlan testPlan=teamProjects.TestPlans.Find(int.Parse("3")); //3 is the test plan id on my side
            // Get test points
            ITestPointCollection testPoints= testPlan.QueryTestPoints("SELECT * FROM TestPoint");
            foreach (var item in testPoints)
            {
                if (item.State==TestPointState.Ready)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.TestCaseId);
                }
            }
```

Then you just need to get the listed CaseID's status. If your want to get the running test Step's results, you could also take a look at this blog: [MTM Testing Scorecard using TFS API](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/10/02/mtm-testing-scorecard-using-tfs-api.aspx)